# Javascript Regex to covert all links on the website from http to https

Tags: javascript, regex, url, https

I want to change all links on the website to https to avoid any mixed content because my developers always forget to change the links.

I'm assuming there is a way using Javascript Regex I can find HTTP and replace it to https

I have tried code like this but it was a big fail.

I believe something along these lines will work

I would like to use the code in the footer of the website so this will work on all pages.

Comment: What links are you talking about? Stored inside an array, .src property of images, href?

Comment: Good question. All links in a href and images so src as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really show any code you've attempted, but this is pretty simple, and can be made even better with clever use of query selectors and some array techniques:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('*[src], *[href]')].forEach(element => {
  ['src', 'href'].forEach(attribute => {
    if (element[attribute]) {
      element[attribute] = element[attribute].replace(/^http:\/\//ig, 'https://');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I love the way you wrote the code but it makes of my links go to HTTP and does not change to https .

Comment: Are you sure? Are you running it after the DOM has finished loading? I just tested it and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Ya, it's not working I have no clue why. I did let the DOM completely load before testing. I think this website has a weird WP code that conflicts somehow although there are no errors in the console.

Comment: If you put `console.log(attribute, element[attribute])` inside the innermost if block, immediately after where it sets `element[attribute] = ...`, what does the console show?

Comment: OMG, it WORKS!!    It did not work on background images and that's what threw me off. Is there any way target the URL attribute? I tried adding it to the code but it did not work adding the Url in the code

Comment: My code.    
[...document.querySelectorAll('*[src], *[href], *[url]')].forEach(element => {
  ['src', 'href', 'url'].forEach(attribute => {
    if (element[attribute]) {
      element[attribute] = element[attribute].replace(/^http:\/\//ig, 'https://');
    }
  });
});

Comment: There's no such thing as a URL attribute. I'm assuming your background image is being set by the background-image CSS property? Because it's in CSS, and wrapped in a `url()`, it's more complicated. You'll have to select every element that might have a background image (so, probably everything with the `*` selector), run `window.getComputedStyle()` on it, then use a regex on the background-image property to parse out the URL, then set a new background-image in the element's direct style based on that. It's not easy.

Comment: Ya, the CSS background-image. Sounds complicated. I better ask another question for this one. Thank you for your help, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this expression or maybe a modified version of which,

```
(http)(:[^\s]+)
```

with a replacement of,

```
$1s$2
```

might be what you might be in search of.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/p7s4HH/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(http)(:[^\s]+)/gm;
const str = `http://some_domain.com/some_link/`;
const subst = `$1s$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This code does not find my existing links to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a HTML collection of all the elements of a specific type using `document.getElementsByTagName()`

Lets say you want to change the .src property of all `<img>`elements.

```
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Now if you loop over elements, you can modify it's .src property using the String objects **replace()** method.

```
elements[0].src=elements[0].src.replace("http","https");
```

Here's an example using img's and a's to illustrate the process:

```js
function replace(htmlElements) {
  for (var a = 0; a < htmlElements.length; a++) {
    var localElement = htmlElements[a];
    var property;
    switch (localElement.localName) {
      case "img":
        property = "src";
        break;
      case "a":
        property = "href";
        break;
    }
    if (localElement[property].indexOf("https") == -1) {
      localElement[property] = localElement[property].replace("http", "https");
    }
  }
}
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
replace(elements);
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
replace(elements);
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com/linkA">LinkA</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/linkB">LinkB</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/linkC">LinkC</a>
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/469/200/300">
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/269/200/300">
```

Comment: This code made some of my links turn into httpss for some reason.

Comment: @Justin - yeah, this happens if it has already been https. I fixed my code above to take care of that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
 $("a").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("href").includes("http:"))
           $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href").replace("http:","https:"));
 });
 $("img").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("src").includes("http:"))
           $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace("http:","https:"));
 });
});
```

BUT, I don't think this is a good idea. If you put this script in the footer, the HTML processor will load all the assets over whatever protocol you have, HTTP, etc. Then, your script will run and possibly change out the URLs. Then the HTML processor will download those assets a second time to process them. If some of those assets or scripts or CSS, then the page will have to be re-rendered, possibly multiple times as it gets saved. There's a performance hit, duplicate asset loading, and possibly page flickering that could happen.

If these are local assets on your server or CDN, a better solution is to use protocol agnostic URLs where possible. For example:

```
<a href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">

or <img src="//myserver.com/image1.jpg">
```

The browser will fill in http or https depending on what protocol was used to fetch the web page. If you can get your developers to use this method all the time, then they don't have to change the protocol.

Comment: The code failed but I love your agnostic URL idea :)

Comment: The code requires jQuery library; I did try it out in a Code Pen. It was working on my HTML. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eweKJQ